# Using opencv on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, opencv

I have some simple opencv files which I wanted to compile on 12.04.

I have installed all the -dev packages

They use:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

at the top of the file.

Using

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` canny.cpp
```

gives `cv.h: No such file or directory`

pkg-config seems to list `/usr/include/opencv` but the directory created at install is `/usr/include/opencv2`

Is this a bug? Any advice?

Comment: If you think it is a bug then report it to https://bugs.launchpad.net/. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've installed the libraries right, the command you're using to compile the code through the terminal is wrong. I've tried it myself, and it doesn't work!
Try the following,

```
g++ canny.cpp -o canny `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

This line should work fine. Please, try it and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package libcv-dev in order to get the old-style header files in /usr/include/opencv/.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your header files in the code with this (Assuming your path is "/usr/include/"):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

and use this to compile

```
g++ canny.cpp -o canny -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

Answer (score 0):

you must include "/usr/local/include/opencv" folder in compile time to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ filename.cpp -o outputfile-name `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Compilation example:

```
g++ simple.cpp -o sample `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Run:

```
./sample
```